# Why is my bootstrap dropdown menu taking up the whole width of the website even though it's so small

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a drop down menu and a input box form using the following code:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            2
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="" value="">
</div>
```

The css I applied is:

```
body {
  background-color: #b6e6bd;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

/* Containers */
.container-fluid {
  padding: 1% 20%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

However, the drop down menu is taking up the full width of the website and the blank input box is showing up on the same line. I did not do anything to style the buttons. Can someone pls help, I need them to appear on the same line.

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image of the result along with the CSS that you have applied?

Comment: @keidakida alright I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, dropdown is a div, and div is a block [see examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

you need to use **grid** or **btn-group**

Or custom method with flex:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="cell">Dropdown</div>
  <div class="cell">Input</div>
</div>
<style>
  .group {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```